# Parsing a DOM string in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, nuxt.js

I need to parse a string containing DOM elements in Nuxt.js

This means that the parser has to work on both the client and the server side and so far I've only found those that work on either server-side only (like cheerio and jsdom) or on client-side only (jquery).

Could You point me to a module that handles parsing strings regardless of the environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [universal-dom-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-dom-parser) . Pretty much just wrapper around jsdom + native dom in browser